# CRC-CCITT String to HEX

Tags: vb.net

I try a function for the " CRC - CCITT ( 0xFFFF ) " .

My input is a string that contains the data. From this I would like to get a HEX value and compare these . Unfortunately, I find no example in VB , which can help me . Here is a comparative example :

DATA :
0095001000020000E15D423C7C803F0327100A0A0BAB991764D00000082E

CRC (ex. http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html):
0x2DE6 (Better just 2DE6)